# "High-pitched": one word or two words?

Tags: terminology

I have always considered such words as "high-pitched", "four-legged", "oft-stated", "first-time", "self-esteem" (struggling to come up with more common examples) single words. For example, I would call "self-esteem" *a hyphenated word*. But [a Merriam Webster editor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/word-of-the-day/lily-livered-2010-05-22) refers to **lily-livered** as *two hyphenated words*. In the audio at 00:24, the editor says "it's **spelled as two hyphenated words**". Technically, are these compound words single words or not?

Edit: added the exact source.

Comment: It depends on who you ask.  The question involves the relationship of orthography to language, and reasonable people can disagree on whether orthography is even relevant to the definition of *word*.

Comment: The kind of hyphenation (four-legged but not self-esteem) you are asking about in English is very common, but they are not all in the dictionary. Bear in mind that usually they are only for a noun plus an adjective and you can invent your own: flight-tested attitude; tummy-tucked look, shrimp-based dish, jackpot-split bettors, etc, etc. This usage should not be confused with a word like self-esteem, which is hyphenated word like: self-control. A fun exercise is writing sentences with nouns and actions verbs and seeing if they work....

Comment: As modifiers, they are single words, morphological compounds consisting of two bases, not head + modifier.

Comment: @BillJ: can you define **base** for us as it is used there?

Comment: "But I have just read somewhere" doesn't qualify as a reference. Some additional research seems warranted.

Comment: @user3169 Didn't mention the Merriam Webster example because I didn't want to use an uncommon word to make things more complicated.

Comment: In word structure, words are made up of elements of two kinds: bases and affixes, e.g. in _friendly_, the _ly_ siffix is attached to the base _friend_, making another base _friendly_.

Comment: @BillJ. Thanks. Can a base modify another base in that analytical framework? Could those "compounds" consist of modifying-base + base?

Comment: I use the terms 'head' and dependent'.This avoids any confusion between, say, "black bird" (head + modifier, i.e. syntactic construction) and "blackbird" (head + dependent, i.e. morphological compound).

Comment: They are morphological compounds, thus single words. The crucial point is that compounds are made up of two or more 'bases', whereas a noun phrase like "black bird" is a syntactic construction with "black" modifying "bird". In compound words, the first base does not modify the second, though it does typically refer to / describe it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, unless a word is listed in a dictionary in a hyphenated form (in which case it's a hyphenated word), what you are looking at is just two words that have been hyphenated.

For instance, there is no single word as **fifteen-legged**:

> It was a fifteen-legged centipede.
>   The centipede had fifteen legs.

In the first sentence, the two words are joined by a hyphen because they form a compound adjective.

Logically, if **fifteen-legged** were an actual word, then so too should be all of the other numerical combinations—but that's neither practical nor, ultimately, possible if expanded to every iteration.  (Note, though, that *two-legged*, *three-legged*, and *four-legged* seem to have had enough popular usage that they've found their way into some dictionaries.)

However, [**high-pitched**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/high-pitched) *has* become an actual word:

> having a high pitch · a high-pitched voice

Although **high-pitched** is serving the same function as **fifteen-legged**, **high-pitched** is a hyphenated adjective, while the hyphen-combined words **fifteen** and **legged** form a compound adjective.

Comment: But the morphological compounds you talk of are single words. Not all compound words are lexicalised of course - many are not, especially the nonce-forms (often concocted on the hoof) such as found in "a custard-pie-in-your-face sketch" and "a no-fuzzy-edge guarantee", where "custard-pie-in-your-face” and "no-fuzzy-edge" are compound adjectives. We can tell they are single words for when we diagram clauses containing them, they are shown at word level as single words, i.e. single constituents, not five or three. Same applies to "fifteen-legged".